# "Непредвиденное появление: 1" в легком коде

Tags: cmd, bat

Решил я значит сделать мини-игру в батнике, и захотел сделать текст из ASCII символов. Делаю, и тут ошибка "Непредвиденное появление 1" Код очень простой, но из-за ошибки мозг все-таки сломался. Если что, все имена я заменил на "имя" чтобы не "рекламировать" кое-каких людей

```
title YaV - Thank for play
echo .  _                                       _                            
echo . (_|   |                                 (_|   |_/                     
echo .   |   |  __            __,   ,_    _      |   | _   __ _|_  __   ,_   
echo .   |   | /  \_|   |    /  |  /  |  |/      |   ||/  /    |  /  \_/  |  
echo .    \_/|/\__/  \_/|_/  \_/|_/   |_/|__/     \_/ |__/\___/|_/\__/    |_/
echo .      /|                                                               
echo .      \|                                                               
echo . 
echo Idea:                   Game by:
echo ИМЯ                     Window
echo ИГРА (ИМЯ)
echo .
echo .            Thanks to:
echo .            ИМЯ
echo .            ИМЯ
echo .            ИМЯ
echo .            ИМЯ
echo .
echo .            
echo Thank for play!
:lol
goto lol
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно [экранировать](https://celitel.info/klad/nhelp/helpbat.php?dcmd=usf_ecran) спецсимволы

```
cls
@echo off
chcp 866
title YaV - Thank for play
echo .  _                                       _                            
echo . (_^|   ^|                                 (_^|   ^|_/                     
echo .   ^|   ^|  __            __,   ,_    _      ^|   ^| _   __ _^|_  __   ,_   
echo .   ^|   ^| /  \_^|   ^|    /  ^|  /  ^|  ^|/      ^|   ^|^|/  /    ^|  /  \_/  ^|  
echo .    \_/^|/\__/  \_/^|_/  \_/^|_/   ^|_/^|__/     \_/ ^|__/\___/^|_/\__/    ^|_/
echo .      /^|                                                               
echo .      \^|                                                               
echo . 
echo Idea:                   Game by:
echo ИМЯ                     Window
echo ИГРА (ИМЯ)
echo .
echo .            Thanks to:
echo .            ИМЯ
echo .            ИМЯ
echo .            ИМЯ
echo .            ИМЯ
echo .
echo .            
echo Thank for play!
:lol
goto lol
```

Comment: если честно про статью там где экранировать символы я вообще нифига не понял, но спасибо

Comment: символ `|` (вертикальная черта) скорее всего читается интерпретатором как `логическое или`, поэтому и выбрасывается синтаксическая ошибка. Чтобы `|` воспринималась просто как строковый символ, нужно подставить перед ним `^`.

Comment: Это тоже самое как: `n` - просто символ строки, `\n` (экранированное n) -  символ переноса на новую строку

Comment: Никакое это не *ИЛИ*. Одна вертикальная черта `|` перенаправляет вывод предыдущей команды следующей.